# Method Not allowed in S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, ceph

I am trying to create a bucket with ceph and s3 library and get the below exception 405. Any pointers to resolve this issue?

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: null (Service:
>   Amazon S3; Status Code: 405; Error Code: MethodNotAllowed; Request ID:
>   tx00000000000000000000a-005d37c963-1009-

Code:

```
        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("", "");
        ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfig.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);

        AmazonS3 conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, clientConfig);
        conn.setEndpoint("localhost:8080");
        Bucket bucket = conn.createBucket("my-new-bucket");
```

Comment: My setup is same as whatever mentioned in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOD8IvxGNq0&t=6s

Answer (score 2):

Try to add below code

```
conn.setS3ClientOptions(new S3ClientOptions().withPathStyleAccess(true));
```

Comment: I also struggled with 405 error when creating a bucket. The same code that worked previously on an older version of Ceph did not work on a newer Ceph anymore. I had to do
S3Client.builder()...
.forcePathStyle(true)
.build();
to get it to work. Seems the newer version of Ceph requires path style access.
Your answer put me on the right track, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck for ages on MethodNotAllowed trying to create a ceph bucket.

Firstly I'd note that you should be able to use the `s3cmd` command line tool to create a bucket with the same user (or you should be able to see the same MethodNotAllowed response) to verify whether it's a problem with your java code.

For me the answer turn out to be this: You're not allowed to name your bucket "documents"! (not sure what other reserved words there are)